# How to Increase File Upload Timeout in Nginx Proxy Manager Docker Container?

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm running Nginx Proxy Manager in a Docker container on my VPS server, and I'm encountering a timeout issue when users try to upload files or perform actions that take longer than 60 seconds. I'd like to increase the timeout for file uploads and other long-running requests. Can someone provide guidance on how to adjust the timeout settings within the Nginx Proxy Manager Docker container's Nginx configuration?

here is how my **docker-compose.yaml** file looks :

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '81:81'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./config/ngnix:/app/config/nginx/
```

**what i have tried**

added the line `- ./config/ngnix:/app/config/nginx/` do the `docker-compose.yaml` file .. and locally here is how my `ngnix.conf` which lies inside `./config/ngnix` looks like :

```
client_body_timeout 7600s;
client_header_timeout  7600s;
send_timeout  7600s;
```

but am still getting the same error which is `504 Gateway Time-out` after 60 seconds of loading .